# Is there a cleaner way to self-reference in Matlab classes?

Tags: matlab, oop, properties, self-reference

If we want to call a function that modifies an object's properties, is there another way to self-reference other than using *obj.property* inside the function?

Example (in other languages such as Java):

```
public void doSomething(int arg)
    foobar = arg;
end
```

However example with Matlab:

```
classdef Foo < handle
    properties
        foobar = 0;
    end
    methods
        function obj = Foo(arg)
            if nargin > 0 
                obj.foobar = arg;
            end
        end
        function doSomething(obj, arg)
            obj.foobar = obj.foobar + arg; % Needed to reference the current object
        end
    end   
end
```

With more properties, it could start to look messy from writing all the "*obj.*" 
I've seen some people use "*o.*" (less characters looks a bit nicer), but I was wondering if there was a better way (ie: without using *obj.*) or is this the only option?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the only option, yes. Passing `obj` as the first argument is necessary because matlab chooses the right version of a function using "dynamic dispatch". I.e. if you have two classes and both define `doSomething` functions, matlab will call the right version based on the type of the first argument; this is why the first argument of a member function (with the exception of the constructor) always needs to be the object itself.

Whereas in java, something entirely different is going on, since it's a compiled language, not an interpreted one. There it's a case of polymorphism, etc etc.

So no. There is no shortcut. This is just how matlab classes work.

Comment: Ok I see! Thanks!  :)

Comment: Not to mention that if your class did not inherit from `handle`, then any functions that intend to 'change' your object, can only do so by returning a new object to overwrite an old object with, i.e. such that you can then do `obj = doSomething(obj, args)`. So, yes, inheriting from `handle` so that you can "pass by reference" is already a "cheat", so to speak.